# Sql connection for executing query

Tags: c#, ado.net

1. I have more than 12k records.
2. Default configured is 30 sec for connection time out. In this scenario i am getting exception like sql connection time out is closed.
3. I configured connection time out 0 for executing from c#.
4. Any disadvantage for set to value is 0.

Please suggest which value is fine for connection timeout. Please keep in mind I have huge data like 12k to 50k.

Comment: **What concrete database system**?

Comment: 12-50k is not a huge data in reality. Also you need to understand the difference between Connection timeout vs Command timeout. Connection timeout is the max time allowed to connect to db server. Command timeout is the max time a command can be run.

Comment: yes you are right, this is not huge data right now but in future record will increase then u can say data will increase upto 2 to 3 lakh per year.  - @nvartak

Comment: about connection time out and commnad time out...can you tell me what is difference if both are taking same value like 0 then what will happen. can you tell me. @nvartak

Answer (score 2):

A value of 0 indicates no limit, and should be avoided in a ConnectionString because an attempt to connect waits indefinitely.

Making connection depends on database,drivers, it is local or remote.
You can not pin point some specific value knowing all these things. value doesn't depends on number of records.

if some problem occur while processing some specific record and it takes too long and you don't want to wait for so long in order to save time. Set CommandTimeout property but it has nothing to do with connection state